# Estimate next observation in a noisy random walk with known variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, weights, random-walk

Suppose we have an infinite sequence of observations $x_n, x_{n-1}, ...$ (going back in time) of a "noisy" random walk: For all $k \leq n$,

- $x_k \sim N(\mu_k, 1)$
- $\mu_k \sim N(\mu_{k-1}, \sigma^2_k)$

Assume that you know each variance $\sigma^2_k$.  What is the best estimator for $x_{n+1}$?

My intuition is that this comes down to estimating $\mu_n$, so $\hat x_{n+1} = \hat \mu_n$ and probably an optimal estimator is of the form $$\hat \mu_n = w_n x_n + w_{n-1} x_{n-1} + ...$$
but it's not clear to me what are the optimal weights $w_n, w_{n-1}, ...$